# Custom legend R plots (Lattice)

Tags: r, plot, legend, lattice

I am trying to add a custom legend to a `lattice` plot but I can't make as I want. Below is my code. I want to make a legend for a `lattice` plot that looks like the one created using `mtext()` but with the symbols I used using `legend`. It would be great if I could make the male and female symbols darker or with different colors.
Thank you.

```
plot.new()
legend("bottom", legend = c("\u2640 12h Ant", "\u2640 4d Ant", "\u2640 3h Ant",
                            "\u2640 24h Ant", "\u2640 48h Ant", "\u2640 72h Ant", "\u2640 4d HT",
                            "\u2640 3h HT", "\u2640 24h HT", "\u2640 48h HT", "\u2640 72h HT",
                            "\u2642 4d Ant", "\u2642 4d HT"),
       bty = "n",
       xjust = 0,
       ncol = 7,
       lwd = 2, cex = 0.8,
       col = c("red","blue","green","pink","maroon4",
               "cyan3","blue","green","pink","maroon4","cyan3", "blue", "blue"),
       lty = c(NA, NA, NA),
       pch = c(15,15,15,15,15,15,19,19,19,19,19,17,2))


#I want to make one legend like this, but mtext cannot add symbols :(
mtext("Antennae:
       \u2640  12h  4d  3h  24h  48h  72h  \u2642 4d
       Head+Thorax:
      \u2640  12h  4d  3h  24h  48h  72h  \u2642 4d
      ", side = 1, padj=1, adj=0, line=FALSE, outer=FALSE)
```

[Here is my current plot, I want to change the legend to include male and female symbols](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62277598/stackoverflow.jpg)

Update:
Here a small data set [data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62277598/stackoverflow.csv)

Here is the R code to generate the Trellis graph:

```
#Command to load packages, not all needed
library("RColorBrewer")
library("gplots")
library("plyr")
library("lattice")
library("Hmisc")
library("latticeExtra")
library("scatterplot3d")
library("plotrix")
library("scales")

#Command clears the console
rm(list=ls())
#Command sets the working directory
setwd("/set-your-path-here")
miRs<-read.table("stackoverflow.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
attach(miRs)
head(miRs)
miRs.st<-stack(miRs[,2:14])
head(miRs.st)
miRs.st[,"miRs"]<-miRs[,1]
head(miRs.st)
summary(miRs.st$ind)
miRs.st$ind<-factor(miRs.st$ind, levels=c("Fem12hAnt", "Fem4dAnt", "Fem3hAnt",
                                          "Fem24hAnt", "Fem48hAnt", "Fem72hAnt", "Fem4dHT",
                                          "Fem3hHT", "Fem24hHT", "Fem48hHT", "Fem72hHT",
                                          "Male4dAnt", "Male4dHT"))

#create list of symbols to use in the legend
supsym <- trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol")
supsym$col <- c("red","blue","green","pink","maroon4","cyan3","blue","green","pink","maroon4","cyan3", "blue", "blue")
supsym$fill <- c("red","blue","green","pink","maroon4","cyan3","blue","green","pink","maroon4","cyan3", "blue", "blue") 
supsym$pch <- c(15,15,15,15,15,15,19,19,19,19,19,17,2)
supsym$cex <- c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5) # otherwise symbol 15 appears a bit larger
trellis.par.set("superpose.symbol",supsym)

#set log scales in the axis
options(scipen=10)
options(digits=10)

#set background color to each gene, can change the color of those genes of interest
bgColors <- c("gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "red", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44",
              "gray44", "gray80", "gray44", "gray80", "gray44")

#color of the text in the plot
txtColors <- c("white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white",
               "white", "black", "white", "black", "white")

# Create a function to be passes to "strip=" argument of xyplot
myStripStyle <- function(which.panel, factor.levels, ...) {
  panel.rect(0, 0, 1, 1,
             col = bgColors[which.panel],
             border = 1)
  panel.text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5,
             font=2,
             lab = factor.levels[which.panel],
             col = txtColors[which.panel])
}       

#plot the trellis graph
print(xyplot(values~ind|miRs,groups=ind,data=miRs.st,
             layout=c(5,5),as.table=TRUE,
             type="p",
             par.strip.text=list(custBgCol=bgColors,
                                 custTxtCol=txtColors),
             strip=myStripStyle,
             auto.key=list(space="bottom",columns=5, pch=8, cex=.8),
             relation="same",
             scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE), y = list(log = 10)),
             yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks,
             main="miRs Expression",
             xlab="",
             ylab=expression('Number of Reads')))
```

Comment: I'm confused. How is this related to lattice? `legend()` is a base graphics function and so is `mtext`. And what do you mean by "symbols"? Can you link to an image showing making clear what you want to change? Even a rough MSPaint image would help greatly.

Comment: @MrFlick I am sorry I forgot to mention that I am plotting a Trellis graph with Lattice. I know these are basic graph functions. The auto.key options uses data from my dataset to create the legend. Therefore it is hard to change it to make a custom legend. I will post a picture of the graph I have and what I need to change. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to plot this using lattice, you're not going to easily be able to mix `mtext` or `legend` with lattice graphics. It would be better if you gave the code to generate the lattice plot with a [*minimal* reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data set -- even fake data for two panels would be enough. There are ways to tweak the auto generated key. Also, i'm not exactly sure what the `mtext` is rendering like for you because it looks off to me. Can you add a picture of your desired output as well?

Comment: Hi. The legend output is similar what @BondedDust posted below, the first option would be the best (with the symbols "pch" that I have now). I just want to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some in-person discussion with the question author, who I think will be satisfied by a legend implemented in `lattice` instead of `base`, which simply requires a modification of the `auto.key` argument to the call to `xyplot()`  Using the same code as above, try this call to `xyplot()`, specifying the legend text directly in the `auto.key` argument: `text=c("\u2640 12h Ant", "\u2640 4d Ant", "\u2640 3h Ant", "\u2640 24h Ant", "\u2640 48h Ant", "\u2640 72h Ant", "\u2640 4d HT", "\u2640 3h HT", "\u2640 24h HT", "\u2640 48h HT", "\u2640 72h HT", "\u2642 4d Ant", "\u2642 4d HT")`:

```
print(xyplot(values~ind|miRs, groups=ind, data=miRs.st, 
         layout=c(5,5), as.table=TRUE, type="p", 
         par.strip.text=list(custBgCol=bgColors, custTxtCol=txtColors), 
         strip=myStripStyle, 
         auto.key=list(text=c("\u2640 12h Ant", "\u2640 4d Ant", "\u2640 3h Ant", "\u2640 24h Ant", "\u2640 48h Ant", "\u2640 72h Ant", "\u2640 4d HT", "\u2640 3h HT", "\u2640 24h HT", "\u2640 48h HT", "\u2640 72h HT", "\u2642 4d Ant", "\u2642 4d HT"), space="bottom", columns=5, pch=8, cex=.8),
         relation="same",
         scales = list(x = list(draw = FALSE), y = list(log = 10)),
         yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks,
         main="miRs Expression",
         xlab="",
         ylab=expression('Number of Reads')))
```

Answer (score 0):

MrFlick's question is as yet unanswered so I am going to proceed on the assumption that you actually wanted a base-graphics solution. The text function can plot outside the user-coordinate frame if the par-parameter "xpd" is set to TRUE, either in a par call or in the text call itself. The locator function returns an x-y value after first clicking once on hte plot window to change the focus and then again at the center of where you want this extra legend/annotation:

```
 text(locator(1), "Antennae:
        \u2640  12h  4d  3h  24h  48h  72h  \u2642 4d
        Head+Thorax:
       \u2640  12h  4d  3h  24h  48h  72h  \u2642 4d
       ", xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

At the moment the request is too regarding location (which is why I gave the `locator()` option. It's also possible to use Hershey fonts using it's astrological symbols where the male is "Mars" and female is "Venus"